# Swift--Subclassed view controllers not inheriting Superclass properties

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, global-variables

I have a base view controller `BaseViewController`, from which all other view controllers are subclassed. Looks like this:

```
class BaseViewController : UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    
//    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    
    var appDelegate : AppDelegate {
        return (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)!
    }
    

    var currentOwner : Issuer = Issuer()
    var currentColor : UIColor = UIColor()
    var now = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())


    
    
    @objc func changeIssuer(issuerName : String) -> Issuer {
        
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        
        let issuerSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: false)
        let issuerFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Issuer>(entityName: "Issuer")
        issuerFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [issuerSort]
        
        let mainIssuerFRC = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: issuerFetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        
        do {
            try mainIssuerFRC.performFetch()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to initialize FetchedResultsController: \(error)")
        }
        
        if ((mainIssuerFRC.fetchedObjects!.count)) > 0 {
            
            if let fObjects = mainIssuerFRC.fetchedObjects{
                for issuerEntity in fObjects{
                    if issuerEntity.name == issuerName{
                        issuerEntity.isCurrent = true
                        currentOwner = issuerEntity
                        print("Current Color is \(currentColor)")
                    }
                }
            }
            currentColor = UIColor.retrieveFromData(data: (currentOwner.colorD!))!
            
            print("In changeIssuer, BaseVC, currentOwner == \(String(describing: currentOwner.name))")
            print("In changeIssuer, BaseVC, currentColor == \(currentColor)")
            
            appDelegate.saveContext()
        }
        return currentOwner
    }
}

extension UIColor {


    class func retrieveFromData(data:Data) -> UIColor? {
        return try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? UIColor
    }

    func encodeToData() -> Data? {
        return try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self, requiringSecureCoding: false)
    }
}
```

I use the properties `currentOwner` and `currentColor` in the various subclasses. The function `changeIssuer` should also change the `currentColor`, as it is an attribute of the entity Issuer.

Trouble is that some of the subclasses appear not to recognize `currentColor`, which I need for a color theme throughout, instead crashing with `[Issuer name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x280946c40`

Anybody have any ideas? I can supply any more necessary code.

All help much appreciated!

**EDIT 1** **Clarification**

On some VCs, I need to specify the `currentColor` like this:

```
    currentColor = UIColor.retrieveFromData(data: (currentOwner.colorD!))!
```

This, even though `currentOwner` is recognized through inheritance, which makes me believe `currentColor` should be recognized as well. They are, after all, defined in the same method.

On others, I need to specify both `currentOwner` and `currentColor`. I first specify the `currentOwner` like this in `prepareForSegue` from calling VCs:

```
popoverVC.currentOwner = currentOwner
```

Then, I have to specify the `currentColor` like this in `viewDidLoad` of the destination VC:

```
    currentColor = UIColor.retrieveFromData(data: (currentOwner.colorD!))!
```

However, I don't understand why I need to do this. Since all the view controllers in the project are subclassed from the same `BaseViewController`, shouldn't they all inherit the same `currentOwner`?

Am I doing something wrong in `changeIssuer` in `BaseViewController`?

Comment: What's the difference between the subclasses that this is working and those that doesn't? Maybe they are in different Target?

Comment: @gcharita--Am checking. What do you mean by different target?

Comment: Project targets https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html

Comment: OK, yes, all in same target...